# DATEDIFF convert minutes to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, datediff

I'm having some problems converting minutes to a decimal even though I've looked at other responses at SO.

```
select cast(datediff(minute, min(start_time), min(complete_time)) as decimal (10,10)) 
from TRACKED_OBJECT_HISTORY TOH1 
where TOH1.op_name = 'Assembly'
```

The result returns, but I always get results like 2.00, 4.00, 5.00 instead of numbers like 1.86, 3.99, 5.03. I guess it's converting after the fact (I also tried the convert function to no avail). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Datediff return an integer, not a float or numeric.

To get what you want, perhaps you should do the diff in seconds and then divide:

```
select cast(datediff(second, min(start_time), min(complete_time))/60.0 as decimal (10,10))
from TRACKED_OBJECT_HISTORY TOH1 where TOH1.op_name = 'Assembly'
```